# how to get a list of wrong predictions on validation set

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Im trying to build a text-classification model on a database of site reviews (3 classes). 
i cleaned the DF, tokenized it (with countVectorizer) and Tfidf (TfidfTransformer) and built MNB model.
now after i trained and evaluated the model, i want to get a list of the wrong predictions so i can pass them through LIME and explore the words that confuse the model.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import (
    classification_report,
    confusion_matrix,
    accuracy_score,
    roc_auc_score,
    roc_curve,
)

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m-braverman/ta_dm_course_data/master/train3.csv"
)
cleaned_df = df.drop(
    labels=["review_id", "user_id", "business_id", "review_date"], axis=1
)

x = cleaned_df["review_text"]
y = cleaned_df["business_category"]

# tokenization
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer_fit = vectorizer.fit(x)
bow_x = vectorizer_fit.transform(x)

#### transform BOW to TF-IDF
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
transformer_x = transformer.fit(bow_x)
tfidf_x = transformer_x.transform(bow_x)

# SPLITTING THE DATASET INTO TRAINING SET AND TESTING SET
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    tfidf_x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101
)

mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.14)
mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)

predmnb = mnb.predict(x_test)
```

my objective is to get the original indices of the reviews that the model predicted wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is another problem in your code, generally the TfIdf vectorizer is fit on the training data only and in order to get the test data in the same format we do the transform operation. This is primarily done to avoid data leakage. Please refer to [TfidfVectorizer: should it be used on train only or train+test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154660/tfidfvectorizer-should-it-be-used-on-train-only-or-traintest). I have modified your code to suit your need.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import (
    classification_report,
    confusion_matrix,
    accuracy_score,
    roc_auc_score,
    roc_curve,
)

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m-braverman/ta_dm_course_data/master/train3.csv"
)
cleaned_df = df.drop(
    labels=["review_id", "user_id", "business_id", "review_date"], axis=1
)

x = cleaned_df["review_text"]
y = cleaned_df["business_category"]

# SPLITTING THE DATASET INTO TRAINING SET AND TESTING SET
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101
)


transformer = TfidfTransformer()
x_train_tf = transformer.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_tf = transformer.transform(x_test)



mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.14)
mnb.fit(x_train_tf, y_train)

predmnb = mnb.predict(x_test_tf)
incorrect_docs = x_test[predmnb == y_test]
```

Comment: When i try x_incorrect_ind i get an Error "AttributeError: index not found"
and the other solution gives the rows of the Tfidf format. Im trying to actually see the reviews that the model misclassified

Comment: I have fixed the code now and also addressed the data leakage issue. Please let me know if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result like this:

```
predictions = c.predict(preprocessed_df['review_text'])
df2= preprocessed_df.join(pd.DataFrame(predictions))
df2.columns = ['review_text', 'business_category', 'word_count', 'prediction']
df2[df2['business_category']!=df2['prediction']]
```

im sure there is a more elegant way...